# How to mock a third party lib which only has concrete classes using Moq,Xunit

Tags: c#, tdd, moq

I am implementing a API which handles different communication between the application and the internet (`WebSocket`, `Socket.IO`, `WebClient` http requests..) the TDD way. Until now I was able to write unit tests for all the methods because I could encapsulate all the calls in order to to mock them. For example when one method uses a http request via the `System.Net.Webclient` I had full control by mocking the `HttpWebResponse`.

Now for the next request I **have to** use a third party library which, at the end just sends out http requests. The problem is that I have no idea how to mock that since all the classes are concrete (most sealed) classes. For the sake of simplification here is a short example.

This would be the method I want to unit test. It sends out a request and calls the callback depending on the response coming back from the request:

```
public void MyMethodIwantToUnitTest(string data, Action<SomeData> callback)
```

The third party lib is quite straight forward, you build your request with a callback and send it out:

```
HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(new Uri("https://google.com"), onRequestFinished);
request.Send();

 void OnRequestFinished(HTTPRequest request, HTTPResponse response)
{
 // here would be basically the logic I want to test
}
```

What I need is to somehow call the `onRequestFinished` in my unity test,with a mock `HTTPResponse` (`HttpResponse` is just a concrete class).
And I have no idea if that is even possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/150480/126014

Comment: This is actually what I was doing before, but one Problem is that the data I need from `HTTPResponse` (data, exception) is readonly so I can't create an instance of it and fill it with test data.

Comment: Since you're doing TDD, then I'd recommend that you apply the SOLID principles and define the interface that the *client* needs, instead of what the dependency provides. That'll probably enable you to get away with defining a smaller surface area. Once you have that (or those) interfaces defined, write the necessary Adapter(s) for that third-party library.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it.
The client code uses IResource.Fetch(url, callback)

Use a mocking framework create an IResource mock & invoke the callback with the required response/data, whenever it is called. Plug it into the calling code as a dependency.

The code in the last snippet in the question, moves inside the real IResource.Fetch implementation. Since this is at the edge, I normally use an integration test - that runs against the real network. 
 If I have a type, whose responsibility is to serialize something to disk/database, I verify that with an integration test that goes full cycle.
Assumptions:

1. There isn't much logic in this type - it is a pass through to the concrete library.
2. Once it is implemented, this code isn't going to be modified frequently

Slower. Better confidence and also bypasses the untestable library issue. I tag them with an 'Integration' category and run these tests once before commit, not after every edit.